# mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Tags: python, mysql

Following is my python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  

import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='qdb1', password='qdb1', host='170.19.17.9', database='qdb1')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

insert_sql = ("insert into qdb1.amis"
              " (CUSTOMER_NAME, AWS_ACCOUNT, AMI_START, CRT_REGION_PRIMARY, CRT_REGION_DR1, CRT_REGION_DR2, DBAPP_INST_ID, DBAPP_AMI_ID, DBAPP_AMI_NAME, VISTA_INST_ID, VISTA_AMI_ID, VISTA_AMI_NAME, WS_INST_ID, WS_AMI_ID, WS_AMI_NAME, DEL_REGION_PRIMARY, DEL_REGION_DR1, DEL_REGION_DR2, DELETED_AMI_PRIMARY, DELETED_SNAP_PRIMARY, DELETED_AMI_DR1, DELETED_SNAP_DR1, DELETED_AMI_DR2, DELETED_SNAP_DR2, SUCCESSFUL) "
              "values ( %(CUSTOMER_NAME)s , %(AWS_ACCOUNT)s , %(AMI_START)s , %(CRT_REGION_PRIMARY)s , %(CRT_REGION_DR1)s , %(CRT_REGION_DR2)s , %(DBAPP_INST_ID)s , %(DBAPP_AMI_ID)s , %(DBAPP_AMI_NAME)s , %(VISTA_INST_ID)s , %(VISTA_AMI_ID)s , %(VISTA_AMI_NAME)s , %(WS_INST_ID)s , %(WS_AMI_ID)s , %(WS_AMI_NAME)s , %(DEL_REGION_PRIMARY)s , %(DEL_REGION_DR1)s , %(DEL_REGION_DR2)s , %(DELETED_AMI_PRIMARY)s , %(DELETED_SNAP_PRIMARY)s , %(DELETED_AMI_DR1)s , %(DELETED_SNAP_DR1)s , %(DELETED_AMI_DR2)s , %(DELETED_SNAP_DR2)s , %(SUCCESSFUL)s)")

print insert_sql

insert_data = ('SERVER1', '68687687876','2014-12-29 13:27:46', 'us-west-9', 'None', 'None', 'i-gtsuid43', 'ami-9jsh222f', 'DBAPP-SERVER', 'i-4wj333e3', 'ami-73eee351', 'VISTA-SERVER', 'i-5464ssse', 'ami-4ddd2853', 'WS-QSERVER', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 1)

cursor.execute(insert_sql, insert_data)
cnx.commit()
cursor.close()
```

I am getting the following error and need help in getting rid of this error:

```
/usr/bin/python ./test.py
insert into qdb1.amis (CUSTOMER_NAME, AWS_ACCOUNT, AMI_START, CRT_REGION_PRIMARY, CRT_REGION_DR1,
CRT_REGION_DR2, DBAPP_INST_ID, DBAPP_AMI_ID, DBAPP_AMI_NAME, EVISTA_INST_ID, EVISTA_AMI_ID, 
EVISTA_AMI_NAME, WS_INST_ID, WS_AMI_ID, WS_AMI_NAME, DEL_REGION_PRIMARY, DEL_REGION_DR1, 
DEL_REGION_DR2, DELETED_AMI_PRIMARY, DELETED_SNAP_PRIMARY, DELETED_AMI_DR1, DELETED_SNAP_DR1,  
DELETED_AMI_DR2, DELETED_SNAP_DR2, SUCCESSFUL) values ( %(CUSTOMER_NAME)s , %(AWS_ACCOUNT)s , % 
(AMI_START)s , %(CRT_REGION_PRIMARY)s , %(CRT_REGION_DR1)s , %(CRT_REGION_DR2)s , %(DBAPP_INST_ID)s ,  
%(DBAPP_AMI_ID)s , %(DBAPP_AMI_NAME)s , %(EVISTA_INST_ID)s , %(EVISTA_AMI_ID)s , %(EVISTA_AMI_NAME)s  
, %(WS_INST_ID)s , %(WS_AMI_ID)s , %(WS_AMI_NAME)s , %(DEL_REGION_PRIMARY)s , %(DEL_REGION_DR1)s , % 
(DEL_REGION_DR2)s , %(DELETED_AMI_PRIMARY)s , %(DELETED_SNAP_PRIMARY)s , %(DELETED_AMI_DR1)s , %(DELETED_SNAP_DR1)s , %(DELETED_AMI_DR2)s , %(DELETED_SNAP_DR2)s , %(SUCCESSFUL)s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 18, in <module>
    cursor.execute(insert_sql, insert_data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 498, in execute
    "Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement")
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

Comment: There's way too many for me to count, but it looks like your `values` list has an extra value, or that your column name list is missing one.

Comment: To use "named placeholders" in mysql connector, as you're doing, the second argument to `execute` should be a **dictionary** having those names as its keys, **not** a tuple (as you're using) or list.  Alternatively, use unnamed placeholders such as `'?'`.

Comment: @AlexMartelli You should post this comment as an answer.  However, I think unnamed placeholders should be `%s` rather than `?`.

Comment: @augurar, done.  You're right, it seems the `qmark` stile is not accepted -- I wonder why I thought otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

To use "named placeholders" in mysql connector, as you're doing, the second argument to execute should be a dictionary having those names as its keys, not a tuple (as you're using) or list. Alternatively, use the "unnamed placeholder" `'%s'`.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is because of parenthesis. here is my code. Check this out. This is absolute.

```
import mysql.connector

my_database = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="kazinaim", database = "naim")

my_cursor = my_database.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO customers (name, address) VALUES (%s, %s)"
val_1 = [('kazi' , 'jatrafbari'),
    ('kazi' , 'jatrafbari'),
    ('kazi' , 'jatrafbari'), ('kazi', 'jatrafbari'),('kazi' , 'jatrafbari')]



my_cursor.executemany(sql, val_1)

my_database.commit()

print(my_cursor.rowcount, "data inserted")
```

Comment: This is not how a person answers on StackOverflow.